# Jhipster, prevent user to update entities created by other users

Tags: spring-security, jhipster

I have been implementing Jhipster at my work and loving it. I was asked to implement a security validation that one user should not be allowed to edit the entity created by other user. For this I need two things:

1. First, in all entities, add a ManytoOne relation with User entity.
2. In Backend put a validation in controller while updating the entity to check if current logged in user is same as what is stored in DB. In front end also same logic to show/hide  edit button.

I have done a POC for this and it works but is little ugly, check the code:

```
public ResponseEntity<Entry> updateEntry(@RequestBody Entry entry) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to update Entry : {}", entry);
        if (entry.getId() == null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid id", ENTITY_NAME, "idnull");
        }

        //here is my logic 
        Optional<Entry> entry_db = entryRepository.findOneWithEagerRelationships(entry.getId());
        if(!entry_db.get().getUser().getId().equals(userService.getUserWithAuthorities().get().getId())) {
            //throw someexception
        }
        //
        Entry result = entryRepository.save(entry);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(ENTITY_NAME, entry.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
```

Is there any better or OOTB way of doing this??? may be something in spring security i am not aware of??

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for Spring Security Expression-Based Access Control, in particular you could annotate your method with `@PreFilter` and a custom `PermissionEvaluator` you would implement with similar logic as in your POC. The `PermissionEvaluator` could be generic and applied to several entity types if you define an `Owned` interface that models the ownership with a method like `User getOwner()` and that all your entity classes would implement.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-access

The annotated method should be in a service rather than in a resource controller.

Also, `UserService` alone will not help you in finding the current authenticated user, you should use JHipster's `SecurityUtils` first and then `ÙserService` if you need more data about it.

Comment: Thanks for swift and clear response Gaël. I am going to check  this out.